# About Methods And Try, Catch Handler in Java

Tags: java, try-catch

So, Here In Java I Am Not Understanding What is Exception e? What does e stand for,  in a catch statement?

```
  Thank You For correcting my statement!
```

Comment: `Exception e` ts a variable declaration. One is a type `Exception` and the second is the variable name `e`. It's no different than `String myString` or `int someInt`

Comment: Exception is the type and e is the name of the variable, like any other function: void foo(Double x). You can access to the variable using the name. Saying that this is a comment because I don't really understand your last sentence

Comment: `catch` is **not** a method, it's a *statement*.  It is code that goes *inside* a method.  It allows you to specify a parameter, and that parameter is the exception that was caught.  The type of the parameter must be a subclass of `Throwable`.  The type also specifies which exceptions the catch block will be used for.

Comment: `Exception e` is what it says, when an exception to what you are trying to do happens, run that block. E.g. if a runtime error is thrown, catch it, and let the program exit gracefully, instead of crashing with no chance of reviving it.

Comment: (Exception ```e```) is just a suggestion. You can rename the ```e``` to anything: ```(Exception error)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the recommended sintax in catch block, the Exception is the class of the exception and the "e" is the variable that will hold the excepcion object instance.

In some cases you will see that a method has more than one catch block so that different exceptions can be managed, in those cases the "e" will vary:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
 // code to manage file not found exception
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
  // code to manage the I/O exception
}
catch (Exception e) {
  // code to manage generic exception
}
```

Remember that **the order of the catch blocks matters**, it goes from top to bottom so if there is a FileNotFoundException the rest will not be catched, as it is more specific.

More on this, it is considered a good practice to be as specific as possible when catching exceptions, you can see some more tips in this article:

https://dzone.com/articles/9-best-practices-to-handle-exceptions-in-java

The Exception Catching thing is a long debate in Java world :-)